# How to get some system stock fonts

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, fonts

I am wondering if I can get some system stock fonts using c#?

Comment: What do you mean by "system stock" fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Getallsysteminstalledfont.htm

Answer (score -1):

Your question is extremely unclear.

You may be looking for the [`FontFamily.Families` array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.families.aspx).